# global name 'fetch' is not defined (GUI TKINTER PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

my professor assigned us a GUI programming question for our INTRO TO PYTHON CLASS. I keep getting "global name 'fetch' is not defined" as an error code. How can I resolve this error code?

The question: Create an investment-value calculator) Write a program that calculates the future value of an investment at a given interest rate for a specified number of years. The formula for the calculation is as follows:

```
futureValue = investmentAmount * (1 + monthlyInterestRate) ^ years * 12
```

Use text fields for users to enter the investment amount, years, and interest rate. Display the future amount in a text field when the user clicks the Calculate button.

This is what I have so far:

```
from Tkinter import *

fields = ('Investment Amount', 'Years', 'Interest Rate', 'Future Value')

def future_value(entries):
    # period rate:
    r = float(int(entries['Investment Amount'].get())*(1+int(entries['Interest Rate'].get()))^int(entries['Years'].get())*12)
    entries['Future Value'].delete(0,END)
    entries['Future Value'].insert(0, r)

def makeform(root, fields):
    entries = {}
    for field in fields:
        row = Frame(root)
        lab = Label(row, width=22, text=field+": ", anchor='w')
        ent = Entry(row)
        ent.insert(0,"0")
        row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
        entries[field] = ent
        return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    ents = makeform(root, fields)
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
    b1 = Button(root, text='Calculate',
    command=(lambda e=ents: future_value(e)))
    b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b3 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
    b3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: You are trying to call a function named "fetch" but you never defined a function named "fetch".

Comment: please apply proper formatting around your code. As written, it's very difficult to read.

Comment: @Novel Thank you, it was a very newbie mistake

Answer (score 0):

On this line . . .

```
root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
```

. . . You're calling a function `fetch()` which you haven't declared in your code.

What it looks like you *want* to do is get the value of the `Entry` widget you declare inside `makeform()`. If you're trying to do what I expect and all you want is the value inside the `Entry` widget then you need to use `.get()`, but even if you did this you're still calling it on `entries`. `entries` at that point in your program is equal to . . .

`{'Investment Amount': <tkinter.Entry object .!frame.!entry>}`

. . . which is a dictionary, not a tkinter widget and as such `.get()` cannot be called on it. Calling `e['Investment Amount'].get()` will return the value you want, but that's all it does. Return the value. To nothing. For no reason.

If you want to do anything with the returned value then you need to actually process it somehow, the easiest (subjectively speaking) way of doing this would be with a function called from the binding. It might also be worthwhile moving your program over to an object orientated style, again this is subjective but it makes it *"easier"* to work with tkinter when using an object orientated approach (subjectively speaking in most cases).